# Should I use CloudWatch alarm or "as-create-or-update-trigger" for my AutoScaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Now I am going to configure AutoScaling for my web application on AWS. I have read several blogs and AWS documentation for a perfect solution of my AutoScaling.

Now I have an idea that I have to create AutoScaling policy (Scale Up and Scale Down) using "as-put-scaling-policy" command. Then I have to trigger the policy using "mon-put-metric-alarm" i.e. CloudWatch (High Alaram and Low Alaram). By this way I can configure AutoScaling for my application.

Again some blogs are describing to use "as-create-or-update-trigger". With this single command we can achieve the scaleup and scaledown action. eg:

```
as-create-or-update-trigger my-latency-trigger --auto-scaling-group sbsgroup --dimensions "LoadBalancerName=myloadbalancer" --measure Latency --period 60 --statistic Average --lower-threshold 0.25 --upper-threshold 0.75 --breach-duration 300 --lower-breach-increment=-1 --upper-breach-increment 1 --namespace "AWS/ELB" --unit Seconds
```

Now I have one confusion that should I use CloudWatch Alarms to trigger instances or as-create-or-update-trigger. Please suggest me. Or give me a guide if my findings are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CloudWatch alarms - as-create-or-update-trigger has been deprecated and only there for backwards compatibility.

From
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-trigger.html

> **Important** 
>   Triggers are a deprecated feature of Auto Scaling. We
>   recommend that you switch from using triggers to using Auto Scaling
>   policies and alarms. For more information, see Configuring Auto
>   Scaling in the Auto Scaling Developer Guide.